# How to display content full width inside bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to create a carousel slider with css, atm works fine on chrome/firefox/IE, it looks something like this:

[image]

Now I want the slider displays full on the screen since it's inside a container, so I added a trick to acomplish that:

```
margin-left:-2000px;
margin-right:-2000px;
padding-left:2000px;
padding-right:2000px;
background-color: #e2e7fe;
```

And ended looking something like that:

[image]

That works fine on chrome, but on firefox and IE can't fully scroll the content. Is there a better solution that applying negative margins and paddings or fix that issue somehow?

**EDIT: I need the slider inside the container since this is an example from my real website where I have more sliders inside the web and not just one on top**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <style type="text/css">
   body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    background-color: #f0f0e8;
   }

   .container {
    background-color: #e2e7fe;
   }
   .slider {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin-left:-2000px;
    margin-right:-2000px;
    padding-left:2000px;
    padding-right:2000px;
    background-color: #e2e7fe;
   }
   .slide {
    display: inline-block;
       margin: 20px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <ul class="slider">
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1068/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/189/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/996/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/603/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/933/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="http://picsum.photos/id/32/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/21/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/22/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/23/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/24/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/25/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="http://picsum.photos/id/26/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/27/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/28/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/29/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/30/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/31/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="http://picsum.photos/id/39/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/33/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/34/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/35/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/36/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/37/200/200"></li>
      <li class="slide"><img src="http://picsum.photos/id/38/200/200"></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
     <h1>Some content</h1>
     <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in. Vel pharetra vel turpis nunc eget lorem. Nulla pellentesque dignissim enim sit amet venenatis urna. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis. Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis. Faucibus a pellentesque sit amet. Consectetur lorem donec massa sapien faucibus. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed enim ut. Id velit ut tortor pretium viverra suspendisse potenti. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. A lacus vestibulum sed arcu. Sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Aenean et tortor at risus viverra. Varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse.
     </p>
     <p>
      Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor neque. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Mi sit amet mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis. Pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus. Sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum. Orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Commodo quis imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien. Sociis natoque penatibus et magnis. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra. Feugiat in fermentum posuere urna. Faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Dolor purus non enim praesent elementum. Erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor.
     </p>

     <p>
      Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus. Interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Mauris vitae ultricies leo integer. Eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit. Pretium viverra suspendisse potenti nullam ac. Eu nisl nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet. Elementum nisi quis eleifend quam adipiscing vitae proin sagittis. Enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum dui faucibus in ornare quam. Enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante in. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus id. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat diam ut. Est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat. Pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse in est ante. Ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam.
     </p>

     <p>
      Dui id ornare arcu odio. Sed id semper risus in. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus. Est ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Nibh praesent tristique magna sit amet. Turpis egestas pretium aenean pharetra. Maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat. A cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque. Enim praesent elementum facilisis leo vel fringilla. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum. Sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper eget. Ut tristique et egestas quis. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo. Sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum.
     </p>
     <p>
      Eget mauris pharetra et ultrices neque ornare. Non sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat. Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus. Libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Venenatis lectus magna fringilla urna porttitor rhoncus. Dolor magna eget est lorem. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare. Id cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere.
     </p>
     <p>
      Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus. Ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie. Sed elementum tempus egestas sed. Donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere. Vitae semper quis lectus nulla at volutpat. Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in. Vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi. Vel risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel. Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien.
     </p>
     <p>
      Turpis egestas sed tempus urna. Fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent semper feugiat nibh. Magna ac placerat vestibulum lectus mauris. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Consequat id porta nibh venenatis cras sed. Volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus. Diam quam nulla porttitor massa id neque. Justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam. Fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus. Aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. Sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed id. Id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum at tempor. Quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar etiam. Aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque.
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take the slider out of your `container` class and replace it with `container-fluid` instead.

Comment: Hi @cristian, you can take the carousel out of container class. It would be resolved automatically.

Comment: I cannot do that since this is just an example, my real website its inside a container and have more sliders in the middle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't want to take out the carousel slider div to be out of the `container` class. There is a fix for that too. I have used viewport width(`vw`) for it and then calculate it in the right way that the carousel will fit on full screen.

**CSS:-**

```
.slider {
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #e2e7fe;
    width: calc(100vw);
    position: relative;
    left: 34.5em;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

But please note that my fix will work only in large screens only (`lg`) termed in bootstrap. For medium(`md`), small(`sm`), and extra small(`xs`) screens, you have to calculate by yourself with same calculation I used for `lg`. Just you have to set media query for different resolutions for `left` position.

**Working Fiddle:-** https://jsfiddle.net/szreLuwn/2/

Hope, it fulfills your requirement.

Thanks